# Верстка сразу на wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

Кто знает плагины, которые позволяют сразу верстать в админ панели

Comment: Может вам поможет плагин File Manager. В нем можно открывать файлы темы прямо в админке и верстать. Если вы это имели ввиду

Answer (score -1):

плагин "page Builder siteOrigin". Нужно на странице создать виджет, выделить созданный виджет и нажать на "добавить виджет" -> "HTML-код" и писать код). Надеюсь кому то поможет

Comment: Это не имеет ничкего общего с вёрсткой.

Comment: @SeVlad и я бы ещё добавил, что этих билдеров - море, зачем называть один? И html они умеют все, начиная с Block Editor из коробки.

Comment: @KAGGDesign абсолютно согласен с "глобальной точки зрения". Но надо ж делать скидку на то, что ТС нуб и для него первая попавшаяся мышевозка - открытие.  *И он ещё не знает какое это зло..* ;)

Comment: @SeVlad Просто у меня на работе, человек, он мне подсказал, что так удобнее. Тип зачем верстать, потом натягивать на wordpress, если можно сразу на wp верстать.